# There must exist a random variable with certain given law?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ and $(E,\mathcal G,\mu)$ be two **probability spaces**. My question is the following:

> Measure-theoretically, is there exist a **measurable mapping** $X:(\Omega,\mathcal F)\to(E,\mathcal G)$, such that $\mu$ is just the **push-forward measure** of $\mathbb P$ w.r.t $X$, i.e., $\mu(A)=\mathbb P(X^{-1}(A))$ for $\forall A\in\mathcal G$.
>
> Or equivalently in probability, is there exist a **random variable** $X:(\Omega,\mathcal F)\to(E,\mathcal G)$, such that $\mu$ is just the **law** of $X$.

For stochastic processes, there is the well-known [Kolmogorov extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem) to guarantee the existence of stochastic processes for given finite-dimensional distributions. But for random variables, is there some theorem to guarantee the existence for given law?

Any comments or references will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general no, but if they are both Polish spaces and the cardinality (either finite, countable or continuous) of $\Omega$ is greater than that of $E$, each endowed with their Borel $\sigma$-algebra and a probability measure, then yes (Kuratowski's theorem)

Comment: Does Kuratowski's theorem refer to [this in wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_equivalence_relation)? It is still not very clear for me to understand your comment. Do you mean the Borel-measurable mapping $X:(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)\to(E,\mathcal G,\mu)$ with relation $\mu(A)=\mathbb P(X^{-1}(A))$, where $\Omega$ and $X$ are Polish spaces, is called "Borel-homomorphism"? But as in [wiki here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_isomorphism), the Borel isomorphism need not preserve the measure.

Comment: Once you have a Borel isomorphism, you can pull back the measure $\mu$ to $\Omega$ and call it $\Bbb P$.

Comment: Ooh sorry, you're so right, i misread the question and thought you had the freedom to change $\Bbb P$. But you can use the borel isomorphisms to reduce the problem to $\Omega = \mathcal E = \Bbb R$. Now you can see that if $\Bbb P$ is not atomic, for instance, you can use generalized inverses of CDFs to construct your $X$. If there are atoms, i think a condition like : if $\mu$ is "more atomic" than $\Bbb P$ (you can map  injectively every atom of $\Bbb P$ to a heavier atom of $\mu$) is necessary and sufficient.

Comment: Great! I get the main point. The necessary (maybe also sufficient) condition is that, both are Polish spaces where $\Omega$ owns greater cardinality than $E$, and $\mu$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\mathbb P$ and "more atomic" than $\mathbb P$. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Consider cases where  $\Omega$ is finite and $\mu$ takes too many values...

Comment: Your example is intuitively a suitable counterexample for the case. But is there some concrete examples, or some references for those examples?